# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) in angular

Tags: angular, api, angular-cli

When I tried to pass the token in the below code am getting a message as "415 (Unsupported Media Type)" in console and in the network am getting message as "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource".

```
fetchFarmerDetails(Venktoken:string) {
      console.log("Welcome");
      console.log(Venktoken);
      this.token = Venktoken;      
      console.log(this.token);
     let url = "http://169.38.82.132:94/GetFarmerInfo";
     var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'";
     //let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'bearer '+ this.token,data1 }); 
     let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token);
     return this.http.post(url,data1, { headers: headers })      
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried adding Content-type in the headers instead of the data1 object. The headers usually contain the content-type and you only have the Authorization right now.

Comment: you mean like this `let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token,'Content-Type': 'application/json');` but it showing syntax error, any idea of defining the same in headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Content-Type`is an HTTP header. If you don't set it, the default value (`text/plain`) is used.

Instead of

```
var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'";
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token);
```

You should use:

```
var data1 = "'InstanceName': 'ORISSA'";
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + this.token)
.set('Content-Type','application/json');
```

You may have to do the same for `InstanceName`